# WinError5 - Python Cannot install sci-learn, sci-kit or sci-py

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

This is the error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\mathn\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\sklearn\\__check_build\\_check_build.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Check the permissions.
```

How do I fix the error and what are the permissions here?
I have tried a lot of different methods and sci-learn package will not install

**EDIT**

After `pip install --user sklearn` the error is:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mathn\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\sklearn\\datasets\\tests\\data\\openml\\292\\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'
```

Comment: I can't know for sure, but I'm guessing that a regular user is trying to install the packages to a system-level directory.  How are you trying to install the packages?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have tried many different methods such as installing using the python package, just installing with pip or installing from numpy and sci-py, but it never seems to work sadly

Comment: Does `pip install --user sklearn` work? If not, what is the entire error message?

Comment: No, it does not work, this is ther error message:

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mathn\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\sklearn\\datasets\\tests\\data\\openml\\292\\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'`

Comment: Have a look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756394/python-sklearn-installation-windows).  Does the answer there help?

Comment: I have already looked at the question in question but windows gives back an error when I try to edit long paths enabled, and just installing does not work :(

Comment: Perhaps solving "error when I try to edit long paths enabled" is the appropriate next step?

Comment: Yes I retried using redegit and it worked, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sklearn installation windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756394/python-sklearn-installation-windows)